# Why did the werewolves start shooting at the vampires in public?

Tags: plot-explanation, underworld

In [*Underworld* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld_(2003_film)), at the start of the movie, the **vampires** followed the **lycans** (a specific type of werewolf) into the train station.

When the lycans spotted the vampires, they started shooting at them right in front of the public with foreign weapons and a strange killing effect on the shot victims.

Why did the lycans start shooting supernatural weapons right in front of the public when they could have just run off and avoided suspicions from the public?

**Why did the lycans start shooting at the vampires in the train station?**

Comment: In the *Underworld* fictional universe, all lycans are werewolves, but not all werewolves are lycans. There is a difference between the two breeds within the lore of that universe, so I corrected this in your question. In our non-fictional universe, there is also a specific difference between lycans and werewolves in mythology (more info [here](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-lycan-and-werewolf/))

Comment: Alright, no worries, thanks for the edit. Anything to get an answer, any edit I will accept so long as it is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, because they can (have the ability to do so).  Before that, the Lycans has always been on the run, but now they have a weapon that can kill vampires (UV bullets), now they stand a chance and can fight back when it's necessary which makes using guns a viable and a logical option to achieve their goals, not a futile or a desperate act as it was before.

Worth noting that using guns won't reveal that they're werewolfs, so there wasn't a big risk in this regard.

Secondly and the main reason is they were following an important target, Michael Corvin, they had to get him at any cost. Later we'll discover why exactly, but you can see how Lucian was angry that the Lycans he send didn't get him,  and then he decided to go get him himself.

Also, the Lycans strange behavior (shooting vampires in public) made Selene suspictious, which led her to discover they were following Michael. It was a minor plot point.

Comment: I think being able to use guns (effectively) for the 1st time is an important part of the reason, they got a new weapon, they took it with them and were planing to use it, could it be for an urgent matter and could also be to save their lives (using guns won't reveal their identity). I elaborated later "can fight back when it's necessary".

Comment: I disagree. And at least it gives context to the situation and shows that they did it because it'll work, as opposed to it being a futile or a desperate act.

Comment: To clarify what I'm saying a bit "Their ability to achieve their mission with this method, played a part in their decision to use it" also, they were fighting for their lives, it's only natural to use every weapon they have.

Comment: Didn't intended it like that, "can" as they have the ability/capable of doing so, with success which makes it a viable/logical choice. If you think there's a better way to phrase it, you're welcome to edit the answer.

Comment: No need to, there wasn't anything wrong in your comments. And I have no problem in deleting/correcting wrong information, or changing the wording if it sounded off or different from what I intended,